# How to display 1,000,000 fishnet polygons in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, vector-grid

I am working on ArcMap. I have created a fishnet with 1,000,000 polygons for pixels of size 0.125 degree. I would like to display the map for a variable that varies across cells. I tried symbology and also converting fishnet to a raster data, but both takes forever. Is there any easier way to do it?

Comment: Dissolve your polygon by the variable, *then* convert it to raster.

Comment: What spatial data format is your fishnet (i.e. db, shapefile, etc)?

Comment: It is a shapefile. What's dissolve?

Answer (score 1):

OK, the solution:

Pick values of polygons by their centroid points, then convert points to raster.